# How does validates_presence_of works?

Tags: rspec

I want to use validated_presence_of with my model.
The following test is falling

```
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :name  }

rspec ./spec/models/client_spec.rb:6 # Client should require name to be set
```

My model on the database does have a :name attribute on the database.

Answer (score 0):

It validates that the presence_of attribute is not blank (has a value). Your test output is telling you that it expects name to be set.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Take a look at the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of)

Comment: I am still not getting it, which object's attribute should not be blank ?